# python children to parent class communication

Tags: python, design-patterns, callback

i have been learning javascript so far but i'm new to python, and i want to do this:

```
def Node():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def callbacks(self):
        # i want this to change the value of the Tree property a to 2, how?
        self.self.a = 2
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def printt(self):
        b = Node()
        b.callbacks()
        print(self.a)

a = Tree()
a.printt()
```

could anyone help or propose a better way to do this or even explain if it's a design pattern ?

Comment: `Node(self)`. The `Tree` instance needs to pass itself to the `Node` instance, if the latter should have access to it. Whether that's a sane design pattern is a different question…

Comment: could you explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the solution for this kind of problem, don't know if there is alternative ways like the binding way in javascript

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent_self):
        self.parent_self = parent_self
        pass
    def callbacks(self):
        # i want this to change the value of the Tree property a to 2, how?:w
        self.parent_self.set_a(2)
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = Node(self)
    def printt(self):
        self.b.callbacks()
        print(self.a)
    def set_a(self, val):
        self.a = val

a = Tree()
a.printt()
```